# Empty element error with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am parsing an xml file using Beautiful Soup but have found inconsistent behaviour when parsing empty elements. I.e.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
s1 = "<c><a /><b /></c>"
s2 = "<c><a></a><b></b></c>"
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(s1)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(s2)
print soup1
# <c><a><b></b></a></c>
print soup2
# <c><a></a><b></b></c>
```

Note that the `b` tag is inside the `a` tag in the first case, but not in the second. I thought that the XML spec meant that `s1` and `s2` were equivalent?

Any thoughts as to how I can deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

The anchor and bold (`<a>`, `<b>`) elements can not be self-closed, so this is invalid XHTML.

On top of that, the [XHTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xhtml1-20020801/#C_2) says a space must lead the slash:

> Include a space before the trailing / and > of empty elements, e.g. <br />, <hr /> and <img src="karen.jpg" alt="Karen" />. Also, use the minimized tag syntax for empty elements, e.g. <br />, as the alternative syntax <br></br> allowed by XML gives uncertain results in many existing user agents.

Comment: The choice of `a` and `b` were arbitrary. I am working with XML tags, not (X)HTML. Also, adding a space does not make a difference.

Comment: BrT: BeautifulSoup is a (X)HTML parser, __not__ a XML parser. Because of this it only supports self-closing tags for elements that make sense. For general-purpose XML parsing use __[`xml.dom.minidom`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#module-xml.dom.minidom)__. I'm not sure whether it supports self-closing tags, but if not you can always do a regex replace for those.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not realise that about BeautifulSoup -- I will have a look at minidom. Thanks!